# Is there a better way to view un-attached source class decleration in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When looking at a class declaration that has no attached, why is it not in plain text allowing it to at least be searchable. Is there a way to view this output in a search format?

Please let me know of a plugin. Thx

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you referring to when you press the 'F3' key on a method invocation (for example) to inspect the underlying code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking here, if you are referring to a class file, then no. You would need to import the source code as a plugin. As an example, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#eclipsesourcecode)

Answer (score 0):

The "Outline" View will display the structure of the class, even if no source is attached, so you can at least see all the class' members, including parameters and return types. The View also has some sorting and filtering abilities, so it might help to find the info you're looking for.

Another option would be to plugin a decompiler, which should open up class files as source files "on the fly". I don't use any personally, but just Google "eclipse decompiler" and see which one you like.